# Word Wrapping Not Working in Bootstrap Theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap Application theme and I have a media-list where in media-body the text is users' input....
Unfortunately if a user inputs a very long word the page breaks and a horizontal scrollbar appears...
I tried setting max-width & width to 100% in body and have tried different word-wrapping techniques on the element including:

```
white-space:pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
white-space: pre-line; 
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
```

but no luck... any idea on why is word-wrapping not working?
Thanks a lot

in CSS:

```
body {

    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

in page (some code changed for security)

```
<ul class="list-group media-list media-list-stream">
        <li id="43434" class="media list-group-item p-a">

            <div class="media-body">
                <span style="padding-bottom: 5px;" class="pull-right close" onclick="Delete();return false;" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                <span style="white-space: pre-wrap;">text</span><br/>
                <small class="text-muted"><span data-utcdate="date"></span></small>
            </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please include the html and css (including selectors) in question.

Comment: @sean Done :) thanks alot.